# Question about the work done by a frictionless rod on a ball on it (Mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, power

> [image: 1]

Please refer to the question, everything is mentioned there.
The answer is option (b) which is $mv^2$

I tried solving this, but could not do it. The problem here is the plane we are using, if it was in a vertical plane, acceleration due to gravity would have made it easier but in a horizontal it gets tough.
It would really help me if you could do or maybe give a hint on doing this.
If you have any problem, please address it to me in the comments. I am new to this forum.

Source-
Pathfinder Book for JEE and Olympiad Physics
Chapter= Mechanics- Work Energy Power

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: sure sir, thank you for guiding me!

Answer (score 1):

The particle will not move until point B comes in contact with it. So, until that point, $0$ work is done. At point B, the particle starts a circular motion RELATIVE to the rod (with the speed of $v$).

The total kinetic energy of the particle when it just leaves the rod (at point A) is the result of its velocity which has two equal components $v$, one horizontal and one vertical (its speed relative to the rod $(v)$, plus the speed of the rod $(v)$). This will lead us to option (b).

Answer (score 0):

If the rod moves to the right at a constant speed, one can put an inertial frame on the rod.  In that frame, the particle comes in from the right with a speed (v), rounds the quarter circle (without friction) and leaves with the same speed relative to the rod. In the fixed frame, the particle starts with no K.E. and leaves with two velocity components each with a speed (v).  The work done equals the final K.E. = 2[(1/2)m$v^2$].